# Is possible to create min/max heap without knowing the final size?

Tags: c, size, heap, heap-memory

I am trying to code a program, which will examine state space of simple game.

This program will use heuristic function, and I want to order generated states in min-heap by the given value of that heuristic function.

But what size of heap it should be? The maximum number of states which could be generated is 9!, which is quite a lot, I think. How to manage this, if I do not want to allocate that huge memory space at once?

I am coding this in C. Any ideas?

Comment: If each game state requires 5KB to describe it, that will need less than 2GB to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will need to store one integer value for each state.
Total size =9! * sizeof int (4byte) = 1.384MB. It isn't quite much! Also if there is no inner loop to compute the states then the time complexity should be O(10^6) and should take few miliseconds to compute.

Yes.you can create heap without knowing the final size.Just use linked list and dynamic memory allocation.